# Select and join from two different tables based on multiple dynamic values that may be or may not be present in the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables where ID field may or may not match, I want to merge the two tables. My bestest attempt doesn't return at all the missing value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
SELECT matricula,SUM(monto) as 'pagosTotales' FROM referenciasdepago WHERE matricula IN('PM0000','PM0001') GROUP BY matricula
) AS A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT matricula, SUM(anual) as 'importeTotal' FROM documentos WHERE matricula IN ('PM0000','PM0001') GROUP BY matricula
) AS B ON A.matricula=B.matricula;
```

After "WHERE matricula IN" may actually contain more than 50 different values.

This is my non-desired result:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| matricula | pagosTotales | matricula | importeTotal |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| PM0000    |         1485 | PM0000    |        16030 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
```

This is another non desired result:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| matricula | pagosTotales | matricula | importeTotal |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| PM0000    |         1485 | PM0000    |        16030 |
| PM0000    |         1485 | PM0001    |           50 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Because it is missing PM0001 where it exists in table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an inner join, try a "full outer join" - this will return a match if it exists, or just a record from A or B if it is not in the other one.

Comment: Thank you, you led me into the right direction, as MySQL doesn't support full outer joins I had to do left outer join - union - right outer join. I can see now why you you answered that, someone edited an extra tag on me as "sql". My only original tag was Mysql